# Periodic ridges in point cloud generated from Real Sense image

Tags: python, numpy, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I have a point cloud generated using color and depth images from an Intel Real Sense camera.

The images were captured using the `pyRealSense` library.

To convert the depth image into a cloud I use the following `numpy` based function:

```
def point_cloud(depth, cx=320.0, cy=240.0, fx=463.889, fy=463.889):
    """Transform a depth image into a point cloud with one point for each
    pixel in the image, using the camera transform for a camera
    centred at cx, cy with field of view fx, fy.

    depth is a 2-D ndarray with shape (rows, cols) containing
    depths from 1 to 254 inclusive. The result is a 3-D array with
    shape (rows, cols, 3). Pixels with invalid depth in the input have
    NaN for the z-coordinate in the result.

    My Changes:
        * Author had divided depth by 256 to normalize, I hadn't done that so I removed it.
        * Output coordinates are in units of 1m. There is a factor of 500 applied at image capture.
        * Author had returned a 3 * 480 * 640 np array. I changed to 3 flat arrays
    """
    rows, cols = depth.shape
    print fx, fy, cx, cy
    c, r = np.meshgrid(np.arange(cols), np.arange(rows), sparse=True)
    valid = (depth >= 0) & (depth <= 255)
    z = np.where(valid, depth, np.nan)
    x = np.where(valid, z * (c - cx) / fx, 0)
    y = np.where(valid, z * (r - cy) / fy, 0)
    return x.flatten(), y.flatten(), z.flatten()
```

Here is an image showing the sort of ridges I am talking about:
[image: Ridges on a smooth surface]

The image is of an object sat on a smooth table.
I can see no reason why those ridges would exist, there are no depth values equal to zero in that area.

Is this simply a legacy of the fact that the inputs for `x` and `y` are integers?